# How to get the proper Octave for SIFT keypoints OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, sift

I'm trying to use OpenCV SIFT kyepoints detection.
The problem is that I'm getting weird Octaves. I've looked it up and it turned out that it's a pack of scale ,layer and octave.

So I've added unpacking as in [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4554)

```
void unpackSIFTOctave(const KeyPoint& kpt, int& octave, int& layer, float& scale)
{
  octave = kpt.octave & 255;
  layer = (kpt.octave >> 8) & 255;
  octave = octave < 128 ? octave : (-128 | octave);
  scale = octave >= 0 ? 1.f/(1 << octave) : (float)(1 << -octave);
 }
```

The problem is that now, I get values from -1 to 4. I want to have 3 octaves and the [nOctaveLayers](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html) parameter doesn't help.
Does anyone know how to get octaves from 0 --> 2 ?

Comment: The Octave tag is for the GNU Octave package. Please read tag descriptions before adding a tag to your question!

Comment: Why do you apply the and operators (octave = kpt.octave & 255). Octave should be obained directly from kpt.octave. What is your input image resolution. Can you provide your SIFT parameters and input image example.

Comment: The problem is that as it is the octave contains many information : (scale, layer and octave). I have to unpack it. The size of the image doesnt matter .